# How to authenticate an access token in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have this code in my ApplicationController

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  def authenticate!
    # unless current_user

    if current_user
      current_user
    else
      render json: { 'error' => {'message' => 'Invalid access token', 'code' => 301 } }
      return
    end
  end

  def current_user
    return @current_user if @current_user.present?
    user = User.find_by(access_token: params.delete(:token))
    if user.present?
      @current_user = user
    else
      false
    end
  end
end
```

and I authenticate a user with

```
class Api::V1::RegisterController < ApplicationController
  layout nil
  skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token
 def get_user
    authenticate!
    render json: {'hello' => 'hi'}
  end
end
```

it throws me an error of `Double Render`.
how can I render an invalid access token message if user's access token is not present in my database and return user details if present?

EDIT1: I tried the code provided by @andrew21

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  class UnauthorizedAccess < StandardError; end


    rescue_from UnauthroizedAccess, with: render_invalid_access


  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  def authenticate!
    raise UnauthorizedAccess, 'invalid access token' unless current_user
  end

  def render_invalid_access
    render json: { 'error' => {'message' => 'Invalid access token', 'code' => 301 } }
  end
end
```

but I get an error.

```
undefined local variable or method `render_invalid_access' for ApplicationController:Class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why don't you raise an error on invalid access, then rescue the error and render the appropriate response.  e.g.:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  class UnauthorizedAccess < StandardError; end

  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  rescue_from UnauthorizedAccess, with: :render_invalid_access

  def authenticate!
    raise UnauthorizedAccess, 'invalid access token' unless current_user
  end

  def render_invalid_access
    render json: { 'error' => {'message' => 'Invalid access token', 'code' => 301 } }
  end
end
```

Comment: I tried your answer but there is an issue. I got HTML instead of JSON,

Comment: The `rescue_from` is not being invoked.  The current `unless` guard around it would prevent it from being invoked in dev and test modes typically.  if you want this rescue_from to be invokable in dev and test, remove the `unless` guard altogether

Comment: take a look now

Comment: Thanks for the reply there was a type error but still i got an error. `undefined local variable or method `render_invalid_access' for ApplicationController:Class`

Comment: Sorry, see correction:  render_invalid_access needs to be a symbol in the rescue from statement.  Give that a go

Comment: Thanks, Brother. you save my day.